# Why is this function not paralleled?

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I have a dataframe `df2` which is a copy of `df`. For each unique value c in column `col_2`. I would like to extract at random 2 rows whose corresponding values in `col_2` is c. If the number of available rows is less than 2, then I extract all the rows. Then I label the selected rows from 1 to 2 in column `batch`.

Could you explain why my function does not do this job for all values in the list `['a', 'b', 'c']`. For example, I observe

[image]

This means the values `b` and `c` are not implemented by the function.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from multiprocessing import dummy
from random import sample
core = os.cpu_count()
P = dummy.Pool(processes = core)

data = np.array([(3, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (0, 'c'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'c')],
                dtype=[('col_1', 'i4'), ('col_2', 'U1')])
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df['batch'] = 0
df2 = df.copy()

def func(c):
    idx = df.col_2 == c
    pop = list(df[idx].index)
    m = min(2, len(pop))
    r = list(sample(pop, m))    
    df2.loc[r, 'batch'] = list(range(1, m + 1, 1))
    
    
P.map(func, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2
```

Comment: Because you cannot share any variables between the main process and other processes.

Comment: @Corralien You meant the variable `df2` are shared between threads? Is there any way to obtain similar result by parallelization? My dataset is big, so it's very slow to do it sequentially.

Comment: How large is your dataframe and how many groups are there?

Comment: @Corralien It has 32717928 rows and 2193 groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure `multiprocessing` is the right answer. Save the code below and execute it. I created a DataFrame with 40,000,000 records and 2500 groups. In this code, you have 2 implementations for multi processing and single processing.

Output:

```
Dataframe: 40000000 records for 2500 groups
[MP] Elapsed time: 5.66 seconds
[SP] Elapsed time: 4.48 seconds
```

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
import time

def func_mp(col, df):
    print(f"Group: {col} ({len(df)} records)")
    out = df.sample(n=2) if len(df) >= 2 else df
    out['batch'] = np.arange(0, len(out))
    return out

def func_sp(df):
    print(f"Group: {df.name} ({len(df)} records)")
    out = df.sample(n=2) if len(df) >= 2 else df
    out['batch'] = np.arange(0, len(out))
    return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = 40000000
    col_1 = np.random.randint(1, 1000, N)
    col_2 = np.random.randint(0, 2500, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': col_1, 'col_2': col_2})

    start = time.time()
    with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as pool:
        data = pool.starmap(func_mp, df.groupby('col_2'))
        out1 = pd.concat(data)
    end = time.time()
    timemp = end - start

    start = time.time()
    out2 = df.groupby('col_2', as_index=False).apply(func_sp)
    end = time.time()
    timesp = end - start

    print()
    print(f"Dataframe: {len(df)} records for {len(df['col_2'].unique())} groups")
    print(f"[MP] Elapsed time: {timemp:.2f} seconds")
    print(f"[SP] Elapsed time: {timesp:.2f} seconds")
```

Comment: I run your code on my laptop. It has been 5 mins and the running has not finished. The cpu of my laptop contains 6 cores and 12 threads. I wonder why the code takes only 6 seconds to run on your machine.

Comment: You run my code with the sample toy?

Comment: Yess, I just copy and run it.

Comment: I've just recorded the process [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19OesXHVNDCUbw26M1PTzeTYB8GXZr5mc/view?usp=sharing). Please have a look at it.

Comment: I don't trust to Jupyter Notebook. Can you run the script from a console please?